# JSON & Rest to ListBox - No Information

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rest, bing

I'm trying to get the main elements to my JSON feed but it won't grab it, only the other items? Why? Here is my code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        string uri = "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=MY-ID&Version=2.0&Market=en-US&Query=Pizza&Sources=phonebook&latitude=33.8563&longitude=-118.1232";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);

    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

            var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(resultString));
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
            RootObject myBook = (RootObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Shops.ItemsSource = myBook.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Results); 

        }
    }

public class Query
{
    public string SearchTerms { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Business { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateOrProvince { get; set; }
    public string CountryOrRegion { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Phonebook
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public string LocalSerpUrl { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResponse
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Query Query { get; set; }
    public Phonebook Phonebook { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public SearchResponse SearchResponse { get; set; }
}
```

So, when I do Shops.ItemsSource = myBook.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Results it adds in the listbox but says ProjectName + Results several times in the listbox...

If I do myBook.SearchResponse.Phonebook.Total, it doesn't have an issue... Some reason I can't get it to give me the Title, City, and so on that are in the "Result" area... Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I believe what you need is DataTemplate

Try

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" />
```

Comment: YOU ARE GOD! I swear I have had issues with this forever! I tried to do the binding thing and never worked... I guess I missed a step!

Comment: Does anyone know where a good resource to learn how to POST JSON Data?